# How can I recover rrd's when my clock got out of sync?

Tags: rras, cacti, rrdtool

I'm using cacti, and I accidentally set my clock set ahead.  Cacti updated, storing new data in the rra's - and now that I've fixed my clock, I can't get cacti to update again.  What do I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to erase these invalid future entries.  Use [rrddump](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrddump.en.html) to export your rra to an XML file, then edit the XML file.  Set all the future time to NaN, and set the lastupdate to 0.  Restore the RRD files using [rrdrestore](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrdrestore.en.html).

Note, however, that depending on how far ahead your clock was set, **you may have lost all your data**!  For a 5 minute average over a day, a clock set ahead 5 days would have wiped it all out!  Same story if you accidently set your clock ahead to 2022 - even a 5 year rra will be completely wiped out.  This is why **it's important to backup your rra's - clock sync is essential.**